# Alternative to display:inline-flex

Tags: html, css, display

I just googled around and found that display:inline-flex is not compatible for all browsers. I am thinking to get expert suggestions over my css below:

```
.badge {
background-color: #B12704 !important;
margin: auto;
font-size: 12px !important;
line-height: 24px !important;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
} 

.label {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}

.label-text {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.container {
    display: inline-flex;  /* this is not comptabile with all browsers */

}

.description-text {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #111;
}
```

Basically, i have a badge and some text beside the badge. This is the HTML portion

```
    <div class = "container">
<span class="badge">
    <span class="label">
         <span class="label-text">
                This is text on the badge
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="description-text">
<p>This is text beside the badge</p>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simplify your HTML markup and simply use `display: flex;` (note that the container will then take the whole width unless you specify otherwise)

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #B12704 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}


.description-text {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="badge">
    This is text on the badge
  </p>
  <p class="description-text">
    This is text beside the badge
  </p>
</div>
```

If you don't need flexbox you can use `display: inline-block;`

```css
.container p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #B12704 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.description-text {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="badge">
    This is text on the badge
  </p>
  <p class="description-text">
    This is text beside the badge
  </p>
</div>
```

If you can't change the markup then:

```css
.label-text {
  background-color: #B12704 !important;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.badge,
.label,
.description-text,
.label-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.description-text {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #111;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
<span class="badge">
    <span class="label">
         <span class="label-text">
                This is text on the badge
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="description-text">
<p>This is text beside the badge</p>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks simpler. Question I would like to ask here - will display: flex works on all browsers? Also, about justify-content
We have limited time for testing, i want to write code which will create less surprise in future

Comment: To my knowledge yes, you can check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (bottom of the page). It looks quite alright, but I must say I'm not an expert on that.

Comment: Same here. I am also no expert. But as per my search, CSS flexbox is not supported on IE9 or below.

Comment: Is there a way to design CSS so that we can get rid of flexbox altogether?

Comment: Yes of course. You can use `display: inline-block;` Way older than flexbox so better supported, but again don't know the details. I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome. I quickly tested on IE. It even works on IE7. 
There is one last request. I cant really change the HTML (due to some restriction). Is it possible to design the same CSS for HTML code pasted in the question. I tried but facing some issue with description text placements.